# How to loop a whole python quiz without using def's?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

The code is below. I am trying to figure out how to make the user able to input 'yes' or 'no' to play again. I tried making the question section into a def by spacing each line forward but it kept putting in the 'expected indented line' error message. Is it possible to loop the entire quiz without using defs

```
import time
#Welcome message
print("Welcome! Have a go at this quiz!")
time.sleep(1)
print("Whats your name?")
player_name = input()

#Questions

score = 0 #this defines variable score and sets it to 0


print("What is 2 + 2 " + player_name)
answer  = input()
answer = int(answer)
if answer == 4:
    print("Well done " + player_name)
    score = score + 1 #This increases score by 1
else:
    print("Sorry the answer was 4 " + player_name)



print("your score is " + str(score))

print("What is 4 + 3 " + player_name)
answer  = input()
answer = int(answer)
if answer == 7:
    print("Well done " + player_name)
    score = score + 1 #This increases score by 1
else:
    print("Sorry the answer was 7 " + player_name)

print("your score is " + str(score))

print("What is 5 + 7 " + player_name)
answer  = input()
answer = int(answer)
if answer == 12:
    print("Well done " + player_name)
    score = score + 1 #This increases score by 1
else:
    print("Sorry the answer was 12 " + player_name)



print("your score is " + str(score))


print("What is 8 + 9 " + player_name)
answer  = input()
answer = int(answer)
if answer == 17:
    print("Well done " + player_name)
    score = score + 1 #This increases score by 1
else:
    print("Sorry the answer was 17 " + player_name)



print("your score is " + str(score))


print("What is 11 + 9 " + player_name)
answer  = input()
answer = int(answer)
if answer == 20:
    print("Well done " + player_name)
    score = score + 1 #This increases score by 1
else:
    print("Sorry the answer was 20 " + player_name)



print("your score is " + str(score))




print("What is 12 + 14 " + player_name)
answer  = input()
answer = int(answer)
if answer == 26:
    print("Well done " + player_name)
    score = score + 1 #This increases score by 1
else:
    print("Sorry the answer was 26 " + player_name)



print("your score is " + str(score))


print("What is 15 + 15 " + player_name)
answer  = input()
answer = int(answer)
if answer == 30:
    print("Well done " + player_name)
   score = score + 1 #This increases score by 1
else:
    print("Sorry the answer was 30 " + player_name)





print("CONGRATULATIONS!, You have finished this quiz!")

print("your final score was " + str(score))
if score > 6:
    print("Great work! You got top marks!")
elif score > 5:
   print("Good, try harder next time and you might get full marks!")
elif score > 4:
    print("You did alright")
elif score > 3:
    print("That was ok")
elif score > 2:
    print("Ummm...Maybe next time you should know study or try harder")
else:
    print("Wow, You are horrible at math...")
```

Comment: Show us the code with the `def` and we'll tell you why it's giving that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break your code up into functions, it is easier to control the flow of code, for example:

Let's make a function whos purpose is to ask a single question and determine if they were right or wrong

```
def askQuestion():
    import random
    num1 = random.randint(1,20)
    num2 = random.randint(1,20)
    answer = int(input('What is {} + {}'.format(num1, num2)))
    if (num1 + num2) == answer:
        print('Well done')
        return 1
    else:
        print('Sorry the answer was {}'.format(answer))
        return 0
```

Now, lets define another function that will assess their final score

```
def assessScore(score):
    if score > 6:
        print("Great work! You got top marks!")
    elif score > 5:
       print("Good, try harder next time and you might get full marks!")
    elif score > 4:
        print("You did alright")
    elif score > 3:
        print("That was ok")
    elif score > 2:
        print("Ummm...Maybe next time you should know study or try harder")
    else:
        print("Wow, You are horrible at math...")
```

Finally, we can define our `main` function, where you can call the other functions as you'd like

```
def main():
    total = 0
    for question in range(6):
        total += askQuestion()  # Note we called askQuestion here
    assessScore(total)          # and now we called assessScore
```

Since we broke the code up into functions, we can call `askQuestion` as many times as we'd like. If we'd like to loop the whole program over again, we can even do that now

```
def main():
    keepPlaying = True
    while keepPlaying:
        total = 0
        for question in range(6):
            total += askQuestion()  # Note we called askQuestion here
        assessScore(total)          # and now we called assessScore
        answer = input('Would you like to play again? (Y or N)')
        keepPlaying = answer in ('Y', 'y')
```